# JavaScript - Creating an array for a knockout tournament

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to generate the blank matches for a knockout tournament. Here is an example of what I mean.

Let's say we have a knockout tournament with 8 teams:
I use `Math.log(teamList.length)/Math.log(2)` to work out that there are 3 rounds to the tournament.

Here is a general rule for working out how many matches are in each round:

```
numberOfRounds = n    [ [2^n-1 matches], ...., [2^0 matches] ]
```

So I know from this that for an 8 team tournament will have 3 rounds, and the tournament will look like this:

```
[ [4 matches], [2 matches], [1 match] ]
```

I should point out that each match is stored as an array, so for example the semi-final of the 8 team tournament could look like the following:

```
[ [team1,team2], [team3,team4] ]
```

I am trying to generate some code which means that I can take a list of teams, and generate the set of blank matches for the tournament.

So if I pass a list of 8 teams to the tournament, the following matches array would be generated:

```
[
  [ [], [], [], [] ],
  [ [], [] ],
  [ [] ]
]
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this? So far I only have the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numRounds; i++) {
      matches.push([]);
}
```

This generates each round of the tournament, so for 8 teams it generates an array of length 3, but I don't know how to generate the necessary amount of matches inside each round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should generate an empty match array for a given number of teams:

```
function genMatches (nTeams) {
    var matchArray = [];
    while (nTeams > 1) {
        nTeams = (nTeams + 1) >> 1;
        var matches = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < nTeams; ++i) {
            matches.push([]);
        }
        matchArray.push(matches);
    }
    return matchArray;
}
```

It should deal correctly with team counts that are not powers of 2. It does generate a slot for bye rounds (when there are an odd number of teams).

Comment: Awesome thanks, the problem is easy enough to think of in your head, but putting that down into a function was puzzling me for ages...appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume if any team which not paired with any team already qualify for next round

```
function genMatches(a, match = 0, stage = {}) {
  let isOdd = false
  if (a === 1) {
    return match;
  }
  if (a % 2) {
    isOdd = true;
    a = a - 1;
  }
  match = match + Math.floor(a / 2);

  stage[Object.keys(stage).length] = new Array(Math.floor(a / 2)).fill([[],[]])
  a = Math.floor(a / 2)
  if (isOdd)
    a = a + 1;
 stage = {...stage,... genMatches(a, match, stage)};
 return stage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a slot for every `BYE` too along with the number of `BYES` in KnockOut Tournament.
if you want the number of matches in first round

```
no.of matches in first round = (teamcount - byecount)/2
```

```
total matches= teamcount -1
```

```js
const tournamentArray = teamsCount => {
  let totalMatches = teamsCount - 1;
 let byeCount = 0;
 let matchStructure = [];
 let log2 = Math.log2(teamsCount);
 let floorValue = Math.floor(log2);
 if (log2 > floorValue) {
        let tempPowerHolder = Math.pow(2, floorValue + 1);
  let matches = [];
  byeCount = tempPowerHolder - teamsCount;
  teamsCount = tempPowerHolder / 2;
  for (let i = 0; i < teamsCount; ++i) {
   matches.push([]);
  }
  matchStructure.push(matches);
 }

 while (teamsCount > 1) {
  teamsCount = (teamsCount + 1) >> 1;
  let matches = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < teamsCount; ++i) {
   matches.push([]);
  }
  matchStructure.push(matches);
 }

 return {
  byeCount,
    totalMatches,
  matchStructure
 };
};

console.log(tournamentArray(55))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function matches(TotalTeams) {
        let teams = TotalTeams;
        let matches = [];
        let extraTeam = 0;

        while(teams > 1 ){
            if(teams % 2 === 1){
                teams = ((teams-1)/2);
                extraTeam  = extraTeam + 1
                matches.push(teams);
            }
            else{
                teams = ((teams)/2);
                matches.push(teams);
            }
            if(teams === 1){
                const add = (a, b) => a + b;
                const totalMatches = matches.reduce(add);
                return (totalMatches + extraTeam)
                
            }
           
        }
    }  
    
document.getElementById("33").innerHTML = matches(33);
document.getElementById("64").innerHTML = matches(64);
document.getElementById("69").innerHTML = matches(69);
document.getElementById("82").innerHTML = matches(82);
document.getElementById("98").innerHTML = matches(98);
```

```html
33 teams will play <span id="33"></span> matches<br/>
64 teams will play <span id="64"></span> matches<br/>
69 teams will play <span id="69"></span> matches<br/>
82 teams will play <span id="82"></span> matches<br/>
98 teams will play <span id="98"></span> matches<br/>
```